# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code.

.ascx file:

```
<div class="DemoArea">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCaseComplete" runat="server" Text="Case Complete" CssClass="btn_contentlist"
        onclick="btnCaseComplete_Click" OnClientClick="scroll(0,0);$.loading({mask: true, effect: 'ellipsis update'});"/>
       <ComponentArt:Dialog ID="caDropDownDialog" runat="server" Modal="true" Alignment="MiddleCentre" AllowDrag="true" AllowResize="false" AnimationDuration="1000" 
                            CloseTransition="Fade"  RenderOverWindowedObjects="true" ShowTransition="Fade" AnimationType="Outline" CssClass="ModalMask">
                            <Header><p class="header">Case Complete</p></Header>
                            <Content>
                                <asp:Panel ID="panSelectArea" runat="server" CssClass="modalMaskContent">

                                   <p><span class="red">Please Note:</span>Once you click
                                        <span class="bold">Ok</span>, your 
                                            case will be Submitted to ACR and you will not be able to edit the Case again. 

                                            <span class="style2">To continue editing the case, click </span>
                                            <span class="bold">Cancel</span>. You will be taken back 
                                            to the Case Wizard and your case will not be submitted to ACR.</p>
                                  </asp:Panel>
                            </Content>
                            <Footer>
                              <center class="modalMaskFooter">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                                        CssClass="btn_contentlist" OnClientClick="caDropDownDialog.IsShowing=false" Text="OK" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                                        CssClass="btn_contentlist" OnClientClick="caDropDownDialog.Close();" Text="Cancel" />
                                </center>
                            </Footer>
                        </ComponentArt:Dialog>
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
CaseContentList obj = new CaseContentList(); // creating the object of case content list control to this page

        LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)((DataList)obj.FindControl("dlstContentList")).FindControl("lbtnDisplay");
        if (lbtn.Text == "Final Page")
        {
            caDropDownDialog.IsShowing = true;
        }
        else
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Window", "alert('Add Final Page First.');", true);
```

But it's giving an error 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: This means that you are either casting it incorrectly or you are not referencing the correct object, please paste your aspx code

Comment: I think one of your `FindControl` statement fails. Try to add checking for null before using of founded control.

Comment: On which event do you call this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CaseContentList cl = (CaseContentList)this.Parent.TemplateControl.FindControl("ContentList");
        if(cl.IsFinalPage)
            caDropDownDialog.IsShowing = true;
        else
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Window", "alert('Please add Final Page to complete your case');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by result of one of "FindControl()" method. The result is NULL and not instance of control.

You must check for null:

```
bool found = false;
var dlstContentList = obj.FindControl("dlstContentList");
if ( null != dlstConentList ) {
   var lbtnDisplay = dlstContentList.FindControl("lbtnDisplay");
   found = (null != lbtnDisplay);
}

if ( found ) {
   // ... do something
}
else {
  // ... do something else
}
```

Comment: The situation is same. You propably run the code before the controls are created. The controls are created during "Init" phase of page.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a DataList and you are looking for a LinkButton, then I would expect you would need to loop through each ListItem within the DataList for the one you want, then find the control in that ListItem

To loop through your ListItems within the DataList you could do this

```
foreach (DataListItem dataListItem in obj.Items) {

if (dataListItem .ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem | dl.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {
        //
        // find the control here.
}
}
```

Comment: can u plz tell me the loop how to find it through a loop

Comment: check edited answer. loops through your DataList DataListItems